# C# Regex : How can I match numbers that are not surrounded by "." and "/"

Tags: c#, regex

I want to code a tool to help us build changelogs by going over the SVN logs. All the commits that I need are made with the format `#100 : Description` or `100 : Description`

In our commit messages, there's a few things that pose problem, such as :

- Updated to version 7.11.0.10
- Merged revision from server/repository/branches/71109 : #150 : Bug description

I need to ignore numbers surrounded by `.` and `/.`

So far I have `/(#{0,1})\d{3,6}/g` that will pick up any number, including the ones I don't want.

Comment: Tried [`@"(?m)^(#{0,1})(\d{3,6})"`](https://regex101.com/r/eU6vM9/1)? Is that multiline text you are processing with a regex? If yes, you need the MULTILINE modifier and the `^` start-of-line anchor.

Comment: You say you want to ignore numbers surrounded by `.` and `/`., but your regex suggests you only want to ignore numbers that are **prepended** by those characters. Which is it? Could you post expected outputs?

Comment: Why not just use a start of word anchor like Wiktor suggests?  Your requirements are unclear.  Please provide more examples.

Comment: @ryanyuyu: `^` is start-of-string or start-of-line anchor. `\b` is a word boundary.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew the second example given actually suggests a word boundary should be used since the number in question could be in the middle of a string, not just at the beggining.

Comment: Then [`@"(?<![/.])#?\b\d+\b(?![/.])"`](https://regex101.com/r/sX7vG9/1) should work well.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, you are right it works for the cases I need. Thank you

Comment: But I see you chose another one. Xiaoy312 solution does not match `#`. Do you need to match `#`? If yes, I will post my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`(?<![\/\.])#?\b\d+\b(?![\/\.])` :

- `(?<![\/\.])` and `(?![\/\.])` will prevent any leading or trailing `.` and `/` symbol.
- both `\b` will assume that the match is a single word
- `#?\b\d+\b` is the actual match for the issue number with `#` being optional

Comment: Thanks, looks the same as with @WiktorStribiżew comment.Thank you for taking the time to explain what each section does.

Comment: The explanation is in fact misleading in the part regarding `\b` (word boundary).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew isn't surrounded by 2 word boundary, the same as saying it is a single word?

Comment: The `\b` before `#` requires a word character to appear before it to get matched.

Answer (score 0):

Could it work to use the spaces around the delimiter to know where you are?

```
[#,\s](\d+)\s:\s(.*)
```

Would this work?
Please add a couple of example lines and i can edit my answer to match them.